# Keep on getting 127.0.0.1 as my IP address instead of 176.191.77.130 with Python socket

Tags: python, macos, sockets, ip

So I've been trying to get my computer's IP address with Python socket programming. Here is my code:

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

However, the output is always '127.0.0.1' instead of the actual IP, which is 176.191.77.130

For your knowledge, I have MacOS. What can be the problem here, guys?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Curious, what do you get from `print(socket.gethostname())`?

Comment: You can only expect this to work if the machine has a name that's registered in DNS. This is only likely to be true for a public server.

Comment: @ilias-sp, that will yield you the name of the machine you are working from. For instance, I will get: 'MachineName-Macbook-Air.local'

Comment: @Barmar it used to work for me for a span of time but now for some reason, it doesn't. Either way, how can I register it for DNS? I am connected to public wi-fi and everything, just in case.

Comment: You could add the line `176.191.77.130 MachineName-Macbook-Air.local` to `/etc/hosts`

Comment: @Barmar okay, even if I add this particular IP to the hosts file, it means that I will always have to perform it manually, right?

Comment: Yes. You can only add to DNS if you have your own domain. `.local` is a local domain that MacOS uses internally.